# SheetRock touching the heating pipe

Tags: heating, fire-hazard

I have recently renovated the basement. I made a mistake of going with cheapest contractor who doesn't seem to care much about safety. I have old style radiator heater on 1st and 2nd floor and pipes are running in basement as shown in image below. I have also replaced my old steam boiler to get a new powerful (146k BTU) boiler. Pipes are going through newly installed drywall and also going up from behind the dry wall.

Should I be worried about fire in case pipe gets too hot? I am not sure how hot these steam pipe will get in winter when boiler runs for hours. Also, I have R-15 Rock Wool Batt Insulation behind the drywall which i am sure would be touching these heating pipes. Is this going to be a fire hazard?

[image: Steam pipe touching the sheetrock wall]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a beautiful 1 pipe steam system from many years ago. I love these systems and they work fine as long as you do not try to make big changes to them. The maximum temperature should be below 230 degrees well below that needed to cause a fire. So, no problem. You said that you got a new boiler? How is the new boiler and the heating system working for you.

Comment: Thanks for responding. My old system worked just great too. I do not have additional heating in basement and plumber who replaced the gas boiler said I don't need one as long as these pipes are exposed. I'll see how the first winter goes. I am in Long Island, NY.